# How to get the type of anything in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In Javascript the use of `typeof()` allows you to quickly see what type of anything is, what is the equivalent in the Crystal?

Say the code below I wanted to check what type Crystal thought the object was.

```
  get "/" do
    object = {hello: "hello", world: "world"}
    object.to_json
    puts typeof(object)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes google works wonders, I searched the API docs for typeof and found nothing. [image]

It is just typeof() https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.4/syntax_and_semantics/typeof.html